# bash script.sh call rails console to def vim and other commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, console

I try not to ask un-necessary questions. I have been at this for 2 days now. I am trying to create a bash script that will allow me to call rails console and def a couple functions like:

```
def vim
system('vim')
end

def ls
system('ls')
end

def clear
system('clear')
end
```

The reason for doing this is I don't want to exit rails console execute vim or ls or clear and then enter rails console again to set all those. Plus I am doing this to learn a bit of bash scripting in the process.

I have tried various ways:

one: rails_console.sh:

```
rails console << EOF rails_console.rb 
EOF
```

rails_console.rb: (I tried it with and without <

```
<<SCRIPT
def vim 
  system('vim')
end
SCRIPT
```

Produces following error:

> /rails_console.sh config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your
>   config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
>     * development - set it to false   * test - set it to false (unless
>   you use a tool that preloads your test environment)   * production -
>   set it to true

when I execute:

```
rails console
```

alone it executes just fine.

I also tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
set -e

# receive $1 rails $2 console parameters.
echo 'echo $1 ' $1
echo 'echo $2 ' $2

# echo 'echo $@ ' $@

# main funciton
function main {
  run_rails_console
}

# execute rails console
# attempt to define functions through <<SCRIPT
function run_rails_console { 
  rails console
  script 
  #| read_from_pipe  
}

# simple function defining vim and trying to execute
function script {
<<SCRIPT 
def ls 
system('ls') 
end 
ls
# | #=> pipes only work in bash
SCRIPT
# read "$@" <&0; | def_vim_in_rails  
}

if $1 -eq rails && $2 -eq console
then
  main
else
   irb
fi
```

I am not even sure this script makes any sense. When ever I use <

Please any guidance or pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to have your rails console start with some functions defined? (Also you might be able to just use `ctrl-l` to clear instead of running `clear`.)

Comment: No experience with Rails console, but the script alone is wrong. In the `script` function, you are using heredoc (for stdin) without even a command. If you wan't to use that script as the stdin of `rails console`, then use it in place. It should not be separate function. Also, in shell scripting no one would define a one-line `main` function.

Comment: Yes I know you can use ctrl-l, but I am use to typing clear.

Comment: 4ae1e1 I am aware that the script is all wrong. I only seperated everything because my brain was swiss cheese and needed to keep each step seperate in a different function. I just want a bash script that executes rails console and sets def vim system('vim') end so that I can run vim and ls or cd or pwd from within rails console, but I don't want to execute all the def functions one after another or have to call require rails_console.rb everytime. just have a bash script load it automatically, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: This is the closest I have come to getting it work, but it enters rails console and exits after running the SCRIPTi#/bin/bash
clear
set -e

function main {
rails console <<SCRIPT 
def ls
system('ls')
end
SCRIPT
$
}

main